# How do you reject (dispute) a credit card debit transaction in India?

Tags: credit-card, india, transaction, dispute

Have you ever been able to successfully reject (dispute) a transaction on your Indian credit card on the grounds that you did not authorize it? (results in a charge back to the merchant).

How do you go about it? I guess this is now not possible for Internet transactions that use a password in addition to CVV (Verified by Visa or SecureCode). What about in case of swipe transactions or phone transactions where you verbally provide your card number and CVV to the call center person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a transaction on POS, where physical swipe is required, the transaction is valid only if it is signed the by card holder.
I have several times disputed transactions that did not belong to me. The card company often make you go round about, but one has to be persistent and it then gets reversed.

On Card Not Present transactions, be it internet or Phone, they are not valid unless authenticated by additional PIN.

There may be certain companies that would allow a transaction without such authorization, but these would get reversed if the card holder complains.